# How to set up Google Drive API on android?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have been attempting to integrate Google Drive functionality within my application but I am not able to use any of the built-in functions therefore I believe I either missed a step or did it incorrectly. I am following the official Google Developers guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started
Yet when I use this code,

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

it displays as red. I registered a project but what do I do with the result, how is it integrated with my application?
Can anyone help, guide me through the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to your `app/build.gradle` file and add Google Play Services as a dependency:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.2.0'`

Then resync Gradle and those classes should be available.

Comment: Thank you this helped. May you help me open up a fileviewer using the Google Drive API?

Comment: Here's how to open a dialog for a text file:

     IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setMimeType(new String[]{"text/*"})
                    .build(gapi);

You can take a look at the reference for the DriveApi class to learn how to use this and other methods: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi#public-method-summary