# Cannot add Google Drive Drive.API, Google authorization worked fine

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I have no idea where I went wrong, but following the link below and using the Google Documentation, I got nowhere.

https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/

And this piece of code seems to not work(Drive.API is not recognized):

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addApi(Drive.API)
.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.build();
```

I've added the API key and Google services version to the Manifest, but this website wont let me post it.

What's weird about this is that Google sign in worked like a charm.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)                   
.requestEmail()
.build();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* 
OnConnectionFailedListener */)
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
.build();
```

Which makes me really confused. On console.developers, I have google drive enabled. And in gradle I am importing google-services, so not importing Google Drive specifically, but I dont think that's the problem. Dont hesistate to ask me further questions or request screenshots.

Comment: did u try this..? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38132225/7012517

Comment: I definitely tried this, since it's in my personal log I write, but this seemed to now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your module gradle,

For Gradle 3.0.+

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.8.0'
}
```

For Gradle below 3.0:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.8.0'
}
```

After that, the library will be ready. Then, import it with the following statement:

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
```